# Не получается вызвать метод при dismissViewControllerAnimated

Tags: xcode, ios, objective-c, ios7, iphone

Здравствуйте.

Прошу Вашей помощи. Не получается вызвать метод главного VC при dismissViewControllerAnimated

MainController.h

```
- (void)alert_test;
```

MainController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
       [super viewDidLoad];
       [self alert_test];
}
- (void)alert_test{
       UIAlertView *alert_window_test....//бла бла
       [alert_window_test show];
}
```

ModalTestView.m - тут кнопка при нажатии на которую мы возвращаемся на MainController

```
- (IBAction)....
   MainController *mainControllerRRRR = (MainController *)self.parentViewController;
   [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
           [mainControllerRRRR alert_test];
   }];
.....
```

При запуске [self alert_test]; работает а вот при возвращении назад через dismissViewControllerAnimated не работает =((

П.С. прошу не пинать если что, только учусь...

Спасибо. Очень жду Ваших ответов.

С уважением, Виктор.

## ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ 1

мм да кода то всего ничего

Есть 2 вью контроллера в стори боарде

1- начальное окно с кнопочкой, 2 - c stryboard ID = 'dddddd11111DDDDDD'

MainController.h

```
- (void)alert_test;
```

MainController.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
       [super viewDidLoad];
}
- (void)alert_test{
       UIAlertView *alert_window_test....//бла бла
       [alert_window_test show];
}

- (IBAction)nazatie_knopky:(id)sender {
    UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *obj1 = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"dddddd11111DDDDDD"];
    [self presentViewController:obj1 animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

ModalTestView.m - тут кнопка при нажатии на которую мы возвращаемся на MainController

```
- (IBAction)nazatie_knopky_nazad:(id)sender {
   MainController *mainControllerRRRR = (MainController *)self.parentViewController;
   [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
           [mainControllerRRRR alert_test];
   }];
```

ссылка на этот проектик
https://yadi.sk/d/Pv06-p68a6yEd

Comment: @delitme, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: не могу понять, почему начинающие так боятся использовать navigationController. Зачем вам эти дизмиссы и паренты? Они нужны для модального окна, которые используются, обычно, не для нормальных ViewController, например для кастомных попаов.

на самом деле первое "здесь" у @Bimawa не совсем корректно. Есть метод, который вызывается раньше viewDidLoad. И зовется он 

- (void)loadView 

он вызовется только если вы его перегрузите.

но если поймете жизненный цикл контроллера, то и будете знать, когда и что вызывается. Это не сложно, просто подебажте с бряками и последите за колличеством объектов.

Comment: еще есть мнение, что в "dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES" нужно попробовать поставить NO

Comment: @tragvar, вопрос не в том чтобы раньше вызвать, а втом чтобы в нужный момент. -loadView вызовется тоже один раз при загрузке контроллера и вьюхи. А @delitme нужно при каждом Appearе вызывать метод, я так понял...

Comment: "еще есть мнение, что в "dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES" нужно попробовать поставить NO" К сожалению не работает(((

@Bimawa наверно вы правильно поняли...нуно каждый раз при нажатии кнопки "назад" в модальном окне

Comment: Расшарьте проект не хочется созадвать новый.

Comment: Окей...2 мин

Добавил в вопрос ссылку на проект

Comment: Обновил свой ответ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Изучите сиквенцию загрузки вьюхи и вьюКотроллера [здесь](http://vastdevblog.vast.com/blog/2012/04/08/uiviewcontroller-life-cycle/) и [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18738210/887325)
А если тупо ответить: "то переместите вызов метода `[self alert_test];` из `viewDidLoad` во `viewDidAppear`, к примеру.

**UPD**

Посмотрел Ваш код, когда я писал `viewDidAppear` я имел ввиду метод, который нужно перегрузить:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
```

Поправьте строчку 26 в файле: "GlavnoeOkno.m", должно работать.

Comment: Спасибо Вам. Что-то вылетело...попробую вечерком и отпишусь...ещё раз спасибо

Comment: Простите за задержку но не помогло(((

Comment: Вспоминается фраза из второго варкрафта: "Нужно больше золота!" Давайте "код в студию" чтоли тогда.

Comment: пришлось править вопрос...спасибо что помогаете друзья

Comment: СПасибо так работает)))